# How to set/retrieve an applicationScope attribute in a jsp simple tag?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am practicing the examples in [Head First Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005407) book.

There is an example in the book which talks about Simple Tags to create a dynamic html select tag. For reference please see page number:542.

I am getting the following exception.

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

I don't know how to set/pass the `optionList` attribute value to the tag handler's setter method. I think that is why I am getting `NullPointerException.` There is no problem with the tld.

### select-beer.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="http://example.com/tags/forms" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Beer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="select.do" method="POST">
<p>Select Beer Characteristics: </p>
Color:
<my:select optionList="${applicationScope.colorList}" name="color" size="1"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Taghandler Code:

```
public class SelectTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {
private String name;
private String size;
private String[] optionList;
private static final String ATTR_TEMPLATE = "%s='%s'";
private static final String OPTION_TEMPLATE = "<option value='1$s'>%1$s</option>";

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public void setOptionList(String[] optionList) {
   this.optionList = optionList;
}

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
out.print("<select");
out.print(String.format(ATTR_TEMPLATE, "name", this.name));
out.print(String.format(ATTR_TEMPLATE, "size", this.size));
out.println('>');

for (Object option : this.optionList) {
String optionTag = String.format(OPTION_TEMPLATE, option.toString());
out.println(optionTag);
}
}
}
```

### Stacktrace

```
18:38:34,039 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jee_war_exploded].[jsp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8000-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jstl.select.SelectTagHandler.doTag(SelectTagHandler.java:40) [classes:]
    at org.apache.jsp.select_002dbeer_jsp._jspx_meth_my_005fselect_005f0(select_002dbeer_jsp.java:101)
    at org.apache.jsp.select_002dbeer_jsp._jspService(select_002dbeer_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception. It tells precisely where the exception happens. And show the code where the option list is created and set as application-scope attribute.

Comment: Added the stack trace. Thank you.

Comment: Now which is line 40?

Comment: for (Object option : this.optionList) is the line.

Comment: I think the tag handler's setter method for the attribute optionList is unable to set it to a valid non-null list. How do I make the setter to receive a valid argument, which is not null?

Comment: show the code where the option list is created and set as application-scope attribute.

Comment: My question is how to do it? Should I use a servlet? I don't know how to set that optionList attribute set as applicationScope attribute.

Comment: I have used a servlet to set an optionList attribute and forwarded the request to the select-beer.jsp. I tried using <c:set var="optionList" value="${optionList}" scope="applicationScope"> in  the jsp, but it gives me an exception that the value attribute of that tag can't have expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tag handler loops over an `optionList` array, which is null by default. So if you don't set this array to a non null value, your tag will fail.

You're trying to set this value using

```
<my:select optionList="${applicationScope.colorList}" name="color" size="1"/>
```

This will thus retrieve the attribute `colorList` from the servlet context and set it in your tag handler.

For this to work, you thus need to have an attribute `colorList`, of type `String[]`, in the servlet context. So the following line of code must be executed some time, before the JSP is ever executed:

```
servletContext.setAttribute("colorList", someNonNullStringArray);
```

Where the line of code should be placed is up to you and your requirements. Since it's global to the application, it would make sense to put it in a ServletContextListener, called when the application is deployed. But for testing, you could also use a servlet invoked before the JSP is. The servlet context is available from the servlet request:

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added another servlet to the project which forwards the request to the current-jsp. The servlet sets the applicationScoped attribute. Now it's working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Inorder to work as the html select tag, do my custom Simple Tag have to include all the attributes of the select html tag? (not just only optionList, name and size)